# ASP.NET Active Directory Role Provider via web.config

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, web-config

I would like to ask if anybody could provide an example of web.config for the following situation:

I have a web (ASP.NET) with form authentification (login controls), which I would like to have connected to our corporate Active Directory. In AD, we have defined users as well as groups. Authentification for the users (allow users...) works like a charm, however, when I want to add role authentification (allow roles...) it doesn't work. I've tried to enable role manager but don't know exactly how to setup the provider to communicate with the AD.

Furthermore, I would like to have all the settings only in web.config, not to do group authentification in the code (I know it's possible but I would prefer config solution only).

Althought I went through several tutorials on the web, most of the role authentification was oriented on using a local sql server or windows authorization, but not AD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea is to write a custom role provider which reads groups from the AD and exposes as user roles:

http://slalomdev.blogspot.com/2008/08/active-directory-role-provider.html

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, I will check it out!

Comment: Suggestion: Add code snippets in the answer, in case the link target goes away somehow.

Answer (score 9):

if that site is on your **intranet** then you don't **need** to use login controls or the roles provider. AD is already a provider out of the box. Your web.config file needs to have

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <!--<allow roles="AD_GROUP" />-->
  <!--<allow users="USERS"/-->
  <deny users="?"/> <!-- Important if you want to force authentication-->
</authorization>
```

the somewhere in your code you can check to see the user is in a role like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("AD_GROUP_NAME")
```

Comment: But I want to keep a possibillity to login as UserA or UserB or UserC, not only as current Windows user. That's why there is a login control (form), just to be able to enter login and password.

Comment: if you need to log the user's actions you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` which will give you the AD username of the currently logged in user

Comment: This does **not** relate to the original question, which is about *Active Directory Authentication* (via "Forms Auth"). Windows Authentication answers need not be posted.

Comment: 1st, this answer is 7 years old... 2nd **windows** auth and ad auth are the same thing

Comment: Most incorrect information does not become correct over time. Also, "Active Directory" in terms of ASP.Net Authentication/Authorization refers to a 'forms base' authentication provider (ie. IIS Anonymous authentication, where ASP.Net performs internal authentication); this is much different than IIS Windows Authentication (which doesn't even "use AD" directly and is most certainly *not* the 'same thing'; it uses NTLM/Kerberos ticketing). Trying to defend such a position without an extremely strong set of arguments would likely result in a failed interview.