# How do I secure a web app using active directory groups?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formsauthentication

Sorry for the basic question, first time with Web MVC4 in C#...

I'm creating a web interface for an application I've written in C#/SQL.  I've been able to attach the MVC4 framework to the SQL DB.  Now I want to secure what people can do based on group membership in AD.  I have the authentication in my web.config set to "Windows" and it properly displays the User.Identity.Name that i'm logged in with.  So I know it's pulling up the current logged in user.  More over, I need to be able to authenticate a user outside of the active directory domain in the case of an android or ipad device.  I haven't gotten that far yet though... for the most part, I'd like to auto authenticate the logged in user if possible  then prompt for a username/password if none exists.

Ok, also I already know how to pull group membership for a user in AD. But I need to run that AD query and store that information somewhere that can be accessed on each page.  Then on each page how do I access that variable?

For example, I don't want to display a menu option if they don't have access to it so that variable needs to be used to either display or not display the menu option that's being secured.  Also, I assume I need to add that security on the webpage as well so that if someone tries to go there manually they cannot.

I assume I don't want to use session variables for security reasons..

In the past with Adobe Flex I used a singleton to manage the session state.  I did a search out there and people are saying that it's probably not a good idea in C#.  Not many examples of this anyway...

What are you doing to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Active Directory Role Provider via web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010461/asp-net-active-directory-role-provider-via-web-config)

Comment: Nice, that's part of my question.  I'm sure the other part has been asked as well but I'm not sure I was searching on the right terms.  If the user isn't authenticated automatically by the Windows auth, how do I store/use a form login into the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would recommend.  Start looking for examples of the [ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx).  This MembershipProvider combined with [Forms Authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) will provide you with a secure system to authenticate users.

Once authenticated, you need to authorize your users to access resources by combining the [Active Directory Role Provider(ADRP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010461/asp-net-active-directory-role-provider-via-web-config) (to determine User Groups) with the standard way of [Securing your MVC Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx).

To get you started I created these simple extension methods when you can extend to use the ADRP (as I haven't used the ADRP).

```
public static class IPrincipalExtensions
{
        private static _adminName = "Administrator";

    public static bool IsAnonymous(this IPrincipal instance)
    {
        return (instance == null);
    }

    public static bool IsAdminOrInRole(this IPrincipal instance, string role)
    {
        if (instance == null
            || instance.Identity == null
            || !instance.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool result = instance.IsInRole(role)
                      || instance.IsInRole(IPrincipalExtensions._adminName));

        return result;
    }

}
```

Then I also extended the default [AuthorizeAttibute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) to give me an attribute I can use solely for Administrators:

```
public class AuthorizeAdministratorAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        bool result = false;
        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;

        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            result = user.IsAdmin();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This uses the same extension methods provided in my `IPrincipalExtensions` so I don't repeat myself.  Some might find this overkill as the following two lines are equal:

```
[Authorize("Administrator")]
[AuthorizeAdministrator]
```

However, since the first example is using a string, a simple mistype denies access, and if I decided to change the role/group name to "Admins" it becomes more difficult.  So using the second one (which I could argue is strongly typed) if the group changes, I only have to change  the name in one location.